# Lubuntu freezing

Tags: lubuntu, freeze, ram, crash

I just installed lubuntu and it was fine until when i opened firefox and the discover app it freeze i tried to go to the terminal but my laptop is unresponsive the only way to get out is to force power off my laptop with the power button. Please help me

Laptop specifications:
2gb of ram
Intel i3 2gen

Comment: Buy more RAM to work with heavy apps.

Comment: You haven't told us what release you are using, however with 2GB I'd for sure ensure i have a *swap* partition (that is default for some releases, not for others but you haven't told us your release). I used a 2GB c2d laptop (older than yours) for testing and didn't have issues, though as stated I use *swap* and I'm careful with how I use RAM. Have you checked your hardware?  (ramtest, visual cap-check,) and did you try SysRq keys to direct kernel before resorting to power button?  What release? Do you have swap? Hardware okay?

Comment: I'm guessing that you don't have a swap. Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's set you up with a /swapfile...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 2G RAM and 4G swap
```

Confirm this /swapfile line at the end of /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines...

To edit, use `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

Comment: Ok i will try it later i hope it works my problem came back

Comment: Ok i added swap 4gb i will give you an update when my problem is solved